# When adding an unimplemented method to a class, is there a way to auto import comments in an eclipse IDE for the method?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I'm creating an abstract class or interface and want to provide some details on an abstract method, is there a way to auto import the comments from the abstract class/interface for that method?

For example: `Letter` implements `Shippable`, and I want the comments to auto import.  I know about the `${see_to_overridden}`, I'd prefer a direct injection of the abstract method's comments

```
public interface  Shippable{

    /*
     * returns boolean based on your class's criteria for if it needs to be insured
     * if your parcel type is not insurable just leave as false
     */
        boolean isInsured();

        String shippingMethod();

}

public class Letter implements Insurable{

        /*
     * returns boolean based on your class's criteria for if it needs to be insured
     * if your parcel type is not insurable just leave as false
     */
    boolean isInsured(){
             return false;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the subclass comments, you can use [`{@inheritDoc}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc) where you want to insert the documentation from the superclass. You also need to make your comments conform to the JavaDoc conventions—most importantly, that they start with `/**` instead of `/*` (thanks to @Puce for pointing it out).

```
public interface Shippable{

    /**
     * returns boolean based on your class's criteria for if it needs to be insured
     * if your parcel type is not insurable just leave as false
     */
    boolean isInsured();

    String shippingMethod();
}

public class Letter implements Insurable{

    /**
     * some subclass-specific comments here (optional)
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * more subclass-specific comments here (optional)
     */
    boolean isInsured(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Puce - Thanks! I missed that in the copy-and-paste from OP's code.